# MKMapView hide base map layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm trying to draw an MKPolyline using GPS coordinates and show the user's current location along that polyline. However, I do not want to show the base map layer, I'd just like a transparent background.

Is this possible? How can I do this? Swizzling? Third-party? Something else? Everything is in play.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rather than diving through the map view's subviews, I would recommend trying to implement your own [`MKTileOverlay`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKTileOverlay_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKTileOverlay/canReplaceMapContent) class with `canReplaceMapContent` set to `YES` and fully transparent tiles.  My guess is that the map view would simply draw its `backgroundColor` behind the tiles, and you could set that to `clearColor`.

There is a [pretty good NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/) that can get you started.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

use empty MKTileOverlay

```
lazy var mapView: MKMapView = { () -> MKMapView in
    let view = MKMapView()
    view.mapType = .satellite
    view.delegate = self
    
    let overlay = MKTileOverlay()
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
    view.addOverlay(overlay)
    
    return view
}()

override func loadView() {
    self.view = mapView
}
```

and render

```
extension ContentViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like,

```
  NSLog(@"mapview background,%@",myMapView.subviews); //here myMapView is MKMapView object!

for (int i = 0; i < myMapView.subviews.count; i++) {


    if ([[myMapView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {

        UIView *tempView = (UIView*)[myMapView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];


        tempView.alpha = 0;

    }


}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: This makes the polyline not visible.